# How many even four-digit numbers $> 3500$ can be formed by the symbols in $\{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> How many even four-digit numbers $> 3500$ can be formed by the symbols in $\{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$, if repetition is not allowed?

My attempt is as follows:

> All even four-digit numbers $> 4000$ plus even four-digit numbers between $3500$ and $4000$

Even four-digit numbers $> 4000$:
$$
3 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 360
$$

Even four-digit numbers between $3500$ and $4000$:
$$
1 \times 2 \times 4 \times 5 = 40
$$

Answer:
$$
40 + 360 = 400
$$

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your approach but not with your calculations. 
The simplest way seems to be to choose the digit of thousands first, then of units, then of hundreds and tens.

$\rightarrow$ 4-digit even numbers between 3500 and 3999:

- thousands : 3
- units : 4 possibilities
- hundreds: 5 or 6, if 6 is still available
- tens: 4 possibilities remain

Hence $1*(3*2*4+1*1*4)=28$ numbers

$\rightarrow$ 4-digit even numbers bigger than 4000, starting with 4 or 6:

- thousands : 2 possibilities
- units : 3 possibilities remain
- hundreds: 5 possibilities remain
- tens: 4 possibilities remain

Hence $2*3*5*4=120$ numbers

$\rightarrow$ 4-digit even numbers bigger than 4000, starting with 5:

- thousands : 5
- units : 4 possibilities
- hundreds: 5 possibilities remain
- tens: 4 possibilities remain

Hence $1*4*5*4=80$ numbers

Total: $28+120+80=228$